# Sublime text: Separate comment/uncomment shortcuts

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I know about toggling comments with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>.

I'd prefer to be able to comment and uncomment lines by using different shortcuts. I.e.: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> to comment and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to uncomment.

Anybody see a way to do that? I'm on sublime text 3.

Comment: As far as I know, it isn't possible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by creating a new plugin:

- from the Tools menu -> Developer -> New Plugin...
- select all and replace with the following

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
from Default.comment import *

class AddOrRemoveCommentCommand(ToggleCommentCommand):
    def run(self, edit, **kwargs):
        block = kwargs.get('block', False)
        for region in self.view.sel():
            comment_data = build_comment_data(self.view, region.begin())
            if (region.end() != self.view.size() and
                    build_comment_data(self.view, region.end()) != comment_data):
                # region spans languages, nothing we can do
                continue

            if kwargs['mode'] in ('remove', 'toggle'):
                if self.remove_block_comment(self.view, edit, comment_data, region):
                    continue

                if self.is_entirely_line_commented(self.view, comment_data, region):
                    self.remove_line_comment(self.view, edit, comment_data, region)
                    continue

            if kwargs['mode'] in ('add', 'toggle'):
                has_line_comment = len(comment_data[0]) > 0

                if not has_line_comment and not block and region.empty():
                    # Use block comments to comment out the line
                    line = self.view.line(region.a)
                    line = sublime.Region(
                        advance_to_first_non_white_space_on_line(self.view, line.a), line.b)

                    # Try and remove any existing block comment now
                    if kwargs['mode'] == 'toggle' and self.remove_block_comment(self.view, edit, comment_data, line):
                        continue

                    self.add_comment(self.view, edit, comment_data, block, line)
                    continue

                # Add a comment instead
                self.add_comment(self.view, edit, comment_data, block, region)
```

- save it, in the folder ST recommends (`Packages/User/`) as something like `add_or_remove_comment.py` (file extension is important, the base name isn't)
- create a 2 keybindings in your user keybindings file for the `add_or_remove_comment` comment command, with a `mode` argument set to `add` or `remove` as desired i.e.

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+r"], "command": "add_or_remove_comment", "args": { "mode": "add" } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+t"], "command": "add_or_remove_comment", "args": { "mode": "remove" } },
```

Note that <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> will override the default Goto Symbol binding, and <kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd> will override the default Transpose Text binding...

Comment: Thank you, that works great! Looks like Sublime Text is deeply customizable.
Also appreciate the override warning!

Comment: Tiny nitpick concerning the "remove comment" command: 
If the selection spans multiple lines, some of them uncommented and some of them commented, it would be great if the commented ones become uncommented if the command is invoked.

I can provide a screenshot if unclear.

Comment: Ok I think I hacked my way around. (If anyone is interested: https://pastebin.com/VigU3HS0)

Comment: ah I confess I didn't test that scenario - apologies! feel free to edit my answer to include your improvements :)

Comment: Is it possible to add comment/uncomment in context menu of Sublime Text ?